# getUserMedia: access system output stream

Tags: webrtc, getusermedia

I know how to access audio *input* devices via getUserMedia() and route them to the WebAudio API. This works fine for microphones and such. But in my use-case, I would rather like to hook into the audio stream of an *output* device. The use case is that I want to create a spectrum analyser for audio coming from a digital audio workstation (DAW) running on the same PC.

I tried to enumerate the devices and call getUserMedia() with the device id of an audio device, but the stream returned only showed silence data. The only solution I found so far is to install an audio loopback device (like Soundflower on Macs) to route the DAW's output to and then use this as an input device for getUserMedia(). But this will require the user to install 3rd party software.

Is there any way to hook directly into the audio stream of an output device instead, before it is actually sent to the physical device (speaker or external soundcard)?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the desktop capture APIs (chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia). An example for chrome is included [here](https://github.com/niklasenbom/RecordingApp/blob/master/app.js#L101)

Comment: Thanks for that tip, will try that out!

Comment: Just saw that this is only available in a Chrome extension. Might work in my case, as my app is running inside Electron. Not sure if it will allow me to select a specific audio device, will check that out.